# Restrict access to one user at a time in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that allows users to enter values and then gives a result based on their entries. When the next user logs in, a script runs to flush the user entry cells so the next user can use the sheet to get their result.  Because the flush script runs every time a user opens up the sheet, if another user is already in it entering information, the sheet is cleared of information whilst they are still in it and then both users are trying to add 'their' information at the same time.  Is there a script I can trigger to run on open to lock the sheet to one user at a time and then release it when they log out or after circa 10 mins of inactivity?  Note that I am sharing the sheet without need to sign in as many users will not have a google account. Thankyou!

Comment: Alternatively you could generate a new sheet for each user...

Comment: Can i generate a new sheet for each new user but still under my ownership? The sheet has protected/locked cells which I believe would be released if the sheet was copied and ownership transferred to the new user...?

Comment: Yes. Create a spreadsheet api: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create

Comment: Today is day 1 of my 'script' journey! Am just getting my head around basics so apologies.  Think I'll have to read up more before venturing in to api creation.  But you are saying it will work so that each time a different user opens the 1 original google sheet it will create a new sheet for them in which they can work.. so eventually I'll end up with numerous sheets which different users have created by opening the original and entering information?

Comment: hmm not quite. They somehow get a link or use a website to open for sheet right? You need to have that link change to the new sheet each time, so that each user uses a new sheet. Or have a sheet with links to more sheets :-)